# $f_n\leq g$ a.e. on $E$, $f_n\stackrel{m}{\longrightarrow}f$, prove $f\leq g$ a.e. on $E$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

Problem:

> $f_n$ and $g$ are measurable on a Lebesgue measurable set $E$, $E\subset \mathbb{R}$, $f_n\leq g$ a.e. on $E$, $f_n\stackrel{m}{\longrightarrow}f$, prove $f\leq g$ a.e. on $E$.

My proof: As $f_n\stackrel{m}{\longrightarrow}f$, there exists a subsequence $\{f_{nk}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ such that $f_{nk}\stackrel{a.e.}{\longrightarrow}f$, i.e. there exists a zero-measure set $E_1$, $\forall x\in E\setminus E_1$, $\lim_{k\to\infty}f_{nk}(x)=f(x)$. Since $f_n\leq g$ a.e. on $E$, there exists another zero-measure set $E_2$ such that $f_n(x)\leq g(x)\ \forall x\in E\setminus E_2$. Then we have $\lim_{k\to\infty}f_{nk}(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)\leq g(x) \forall x\in E\setminus (E_1\cup E_2)$. $m(E_1\cup E_2)=0$, thus $f\leq g$ a.e. on $E$.

Is there any problem in my proof? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is not rigorous. $f_n \leq f$ a e only tells us that there us  set $A_n$ of measure $0$ such that $f_n(x) \leq f(x)$ whenever $x \notin A_n$. You have to take your $E_2$ as the union of the $A_n$'s. Also you only have to write $f_{n_k}(x) \leq g(x)$ for $x \notin E_1\cup E_2$ and take limit as $k \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks. That is one problem. I am also worried about "$\lim_{k\to\infty}f_{nk}(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$". If a subquence of a sequence converges, can I say the original sequence converges to the same limit point?

Comment: @Guanfei See my answer now.

Comment: But do we know $f_n\to f$?

Comment: @Guanfei Sorry, I deleted the last sentence. There is no need to talk about $\lim f_n(x)$ anywhere. Just use only the subsbequence $(f_{n_k})$.

Comment: Right. There is no need to mention $f_n$ if we use its subsequence. Thanks again.